# rvm No such file or directory

Tags: ruby, rvm

Used this way installed RVM:

```
gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys D39DC0E3
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh
```

Then removed it:

```
rvm implode
```

Delete all relation files:

```
rm -rf /usr/local/rvm
sudo rm /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh
sudo rm /etc/rvmrc
sudo rm ~/.rvmrc
```

And checked all config files:

```
~/.bashrc 
~/.bash_profile 
~/.profile
```

And source them again.

I did all I can do. But when I ran `cd` to change a directory, got error:

```
-bash: /usr/local/rvm/scripts/initialize: No such file or directory
-bash: /usr/local/rvm/scripts/hook: No such file or directory
```

Where these path been called?

Comment: Did you restart your terminal? `rvm` defines `cd` as an alias; if you're still running the same shell, it looks like it is still defined for you. You should be able to access the original `cd` using `\cd`. You might remove the alias in your current shell using `unalias cd`. Rerunning your config files will not remove it for you.

Comment: @Amadan You are right. After restart terminal, it looks good.